# A single building is represented as several smaller buildings in GML file

Tags: gml, citygml, building

A single building is divided into several different parts and expressed with different building identities in the GML file that I need to study. Is there any way to fix such an error?

Comment: What makes you think that it is an error? Maybe the data provider wants to express the building that way. The parts may have different attributes.

Comment: Some parts are quite small and oddly shaped, such as triangular prisms.

Comment: Ok, automatic programs that build 3D objects from for example lidar data tend to make such artifacts. Maybe you have that kind of data. Unfortunately I do not know how to fix the buildings.